# regex substitution between two files with regex expression

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

regex substitution between two files with regex expression

Everywhere i can find only the substitution of 1 regex in a file ,Iam looking to read the regex in file A and substitute it with value in file B
Tried , using this code  but unable to do .

```
import re
import itertools
from ast import literal_eval
dict={}
daddy=(str(tuple(i.strip('\n') for i in open('CanIfcousin.h','r'))))
d = eval(str(re.split('\s+', daddy)))

content = (str(tuple(i.strip('\n') for i in open('CanIfcousin2.h','r'))))
with open('r1.h', 'w') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join(re.sub('^(#define[^\S\n]+\w+VERSION[^\S\n]+\()[A-Z0-9]+(?=\))',  lambda x:d[x.group(r'\g<1> 00 ')], i) for i in content))
```

This is the output

T
h
i
s

d
o
c
u
m
e
n
t

and rest of the whole file ,single character in new line a bit gibberish

``````
example 

input1 = File1

##a.h

#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (1U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (2U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (3U)
#define TEST_CANTRCV_MODULE_ID             (70U)  /* 0x46 */

input 2 = File2
##a.h
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (FFFU)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (1XFFUU)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (2X000FFFU)
#define TEST_McalModule_CanTp_ID            (70U)  /* 0x46 */

OUTPUT = File3
##a.h

#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (1U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (2U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (3U)
#define TEST_McalModule_CanTp_ID             (70U)  /* 0x46 */
`````
``````

Comment: The shown code can't produce this output. "content" is a string and has no method "group".

Comment: this is what i have ran it in vs code sir @MichaelButscher I double checked it

Comment: The output doesn't appear correctly I assume.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is complex, so you need to split it into several simpler tasks, solve them separately and then combine solutions into one. Basically we can split your task into 3 "subtasks":

1. Compare two directories and find files with same filename;
2. Find all matches of regular expression in first file;
3. Generate search and replace regular expressions using each match from first file and apply them.

---

1. To not reinvent the wheel you can use [`filecmp.dircmp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#the-dircmp-class) to compare two directories and specifically [`.common_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.dircmp.common_files) to get list of filenames present in both folders.

   ```py
   from filecmp import dircmp

   result = dircmp(r"some/path/dir1", r"some/path/dir2").common_files
   ```
2. To find matches of particular regular expression in file we need to read all file content and use either [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) *(if we want to get all matches in list)* or [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) *(if we want to work with [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) which yields [`Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) objects)*. Also we can compile pattern *(using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile))* and call [`.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) or [`.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) of returned [`Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) object.

   You can stay with your regular expression, but in this example I'll use [`#define\s*(.+?VERSION)\s*\((.+?)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/B88PMr/1) which will return me name of defined constant in first group and it's value in second.

   ```py
   import re

   pattern = re.compile(r"#define\s*(.+?VERSION)\s*\((.+?)\)")
   with open(r"some/path/dir1/a.h") as f:
       for match in pattern.finditer(f.read()):
           print(*match.groups())
   ```
3. From previous step we know that first group of match contains name and second contains value. Our task is to replace value in definition of constant with same name in another file, so we need to dynamically build regular expression to find constant with same name and also build replacement which will change just value inside parentheses.

   If we want to use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) we need to build pattern which will capture all text *before* value we need to change in *first group*, all text *after* value in *second group* and build replacement which will keep first and second group with new value. Let's say that we need to replace value of constant `CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION` with `3U`. Using described logic our pattern should look like this [`(#define\s*CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION\s*\().+?(\).*?)`](https://regex101.com/r/HPr9Hr/1) and replacement should include new value between groups `\g<1>3U\g<2>`.

   We can declare two "format-ready" string for search pattern and replacement and use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in code to insert values from every match found in first file. We need to read content of second file and replace it every loop iteration after replacement done. I'd recommend also to escape all special chars in obtained matches *(using [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape))* to prevent any possible errors.

   ```py
   import re

   pattern = re.compile(r"#define\s*(.+?VERSION)\s*\((.+?)\)")
   search = r"(#define\s*{}\s*\().+?(\).*?)"
   replace = r"\g<1>{}\g<2>"
   with open(r"some/path/dir1/a.h") as f1, open(r"some/path/dir2/a.h") as f2, \
           open(r"some/path/dir3/a.h", "w") as out:
       final = f2.read()
       for match in pattern.finditer(f.read()):
           final = re.sub(
                search.format(re.escape(match.group(1))),
                replace.format(re.escape(match.group(2))),
                final
            )
        out.write(final)
   ```

---

Now we need to combine three solutions above into a one. To all file-related operations I'll use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) and it's methods, but you can use also functions from [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), check [*Correspondence to tools in the `os` module*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
from filecmp import dircmp

src_dir1 = Path(r"some/path/dir1")
src_dir2 = Path(r"some/path/dir2")
dst_dir = Path(r"some/path/dir3")

dst_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
pattern = re.compile(r"#define\s*(.+?VERSION)\s*\((.+?)\)")
search = r"(#define\s*{}\s*\().+?(\).*?)"
replace = r"\g<1>{}\g<2>"

for fn in dircmp(src_dir1, src_dir2).common_files:
    with (src_dir1 / fn).open() as f1, (src_dir2 / fn).open() as f2,\
            (dst_dir / fn).open("w") as out_f:
        final = f2.read()
        for m in pattern.finditer(f1.read()):
            final = re.sub(
                search.format(re.escape(m.group(1))),
                replace.format(re.escape(m.group(2))),
                final
            )
        out_f.write(final)
```

---

**Upd.** From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72881370/10824407#comment128739750_72888140) comment I assume that author wants to modify content of files in second folder, so third folder isn't required at all, we just need to open second file in `r+` mode, read all content *(Using [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read))* then return cursor to beginning of file *(Using [`.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek))*, write new content and cut all remaining data *(Using [`.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate))*:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
from filecmp import dircmp

src_dir1 = Path(r"some/path/dir1")
src_dir2 = Path(r"some/path/dir2")

pattern = re.compile(r"#define\s*(.+?VERSION)\s*\((.+?)\)")
search = r"(#define\s*{}\s*\().+?(\).*?)"
replace = r"\g<1>{}\g<2>"

for fn in dircmp(src_dir1, src_dir2).common_files:
    with (src_dir1 / fn).open() as f1, (src_dir2 / fn).open("r+") as f2:
        final = f2.read()
        for m in pattern.finditer(f1.read()):
            final = re.sub(
                search.format(re.escape(m.group(1))),
                replace.format(re.escape(m.group(2))),
                final
            )
        f2.seek(0)
        f2.write(final)
        f2.truncate()
```

You might also want to add some "backup" when modifying files. Simplest is to copy file before modification and save it's copy with same name but with adding `.bak` extension using [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile). Just add one line right after start of outer loop:

```py
from shutil import copyfile

...

for fn in dircmp(src_dir1, src_dir2).common_files:
    copyfile(src_dir2 / fn, src_dir2 / (fn + ".bak"))
    
    ...
```

Comment: hi @Olvin Roght  what iam trying to do here is taking two folders each have files with same names ex: (folder/a.h ,b.h,c.txt) , (folder2/a.h,b.h,c.txt) here iam looking to take files with same names with folder as input and use regex on each file with the declared regex expression in the code and give output to a folder3 with the same file names and at the end folder 2 is updated with folder 3 .

Comment: Hello, @PATHI, except last part *(updating folder2 with content of folder3)* I suppose provided solution does exactly what you explained. If your final task is to modify files in *folder2* with values of constants from *folder1* you can omit saving changes to *folder3* and just rewrite files in *folder2* instantly.

Comment: can you please  help a bit  sir @Olvin Roght

Comment: @PATHI, you can use `"r+"` mode when opening file from *folder2* and rewrite content of this file with new after you read it in string, so no *folder3* involved at all.

Comment: it is giving Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\python freak]\jackiechan.py", line 34, in <module>
    merger(file1, file2, pattern2)
TypeError: merger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'  error

Comment: @PATHI, I have not `merger()` function in my code sample, so I can't tell what exactly throw an error after you've modified code. Also, I've added example which won't create any extra folders but modify files in *folder2*.

Comment: Has the question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've correctly understood your requirements (for each entry in file2, get the corresponding value in file1 if possible, else put the file2 value), I've come up with this:

```py
import re
import os

def merger(i1, i2, o, p):
    output = []
    content2 = i2.readline()
    while content2 != "":
        result2 = p.match(content2)
        try:
            to_search = result2.group(1)
            pattern1 = re.compile(f"#define {to_search}.*\(([A-Za-z0-9]+)\)")
            content1 = i1.readline()
            while content1 != "":
                result1 = pattern1.match(content1)
                try:
                    to_add = result1.group(1)
                    output.append(result2.group(0) + "(" + to_add + ")")
                    break
                except:
                    content1 = i1.readline()
        except:
            output.append(content2)
        content2 = i2.readline()
    o.write("\n".join(output))

pattern2 = re.compile("#define ([A-Z_]*VERSION)[^\(]*")

folder1 = "data/folder1"
folder2 = "data/folder2"
folder3 = "data/folder3"

for elt in os.listdir(folder1):
    file1 = open(os.path.join(folder1, elt), "r")
    file2 = open(os.path.join(folder2, elt), "r")
    file3 = open(os.path.join(folder3, elt), "w")
    merger(file1, file2, file3, pattern2)
```

This should do the job. Not the cleanest way to do I think, though.

In order to then replace `folder 2` with `folder 3`:

```py
import shutil
import os

folder2 = "data/folder2"
folder3 = "data/folder3"

shutil.rmtree(folder2)
os.rename(folder3, folder2)
```

Comment: Does it answer your issue?

Comment: it does but is it possible to give a file path for multiple files ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am not aware of a native function that does exactly this, taking multiple file paths, a regular expression and writes it into an output file. The solution is for you to create it (what have been done here). If it wasn't created, I'd assume it is because it is such a specific usage that it wasn't worth giving everybody access to this? In any case, this is one way to do. Here, you can give multiple paths `file1` and `file2` haven't been declared with the same path (`data/file1` and `data/file2`)

Comment: sorry for not clarifying properly , what iam trying to do here is taking two folders each have files with same names ex: (folder/a.h ,b.h,c.txt)   , (folder2/a.h,b.h,c.txt)  here iam looking to take files with same names with folder as input and use regex on each file with the declared regex expression in the code and give output to a folder3 with the same file names .

Comment: I modified the answer. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: hi @GregoirePelegrin sorry for late reply , yes it worked for a single file will test it for multiple files tomorrow, but is it possible to update contents of folder 2 with folder 3 after comparision such that there is only folder 1 and folder 2 at the end . also i would like to buy you a cofee/drink for the help :)

Comment: More realistically, you'll want to delete folder 2 and rename folder 3. I added this in the reply. Additionally, although I don't need the money, there are plenty of non-profit that do. I you really want to give, give to them, this will certainly prove more useful! Also mark the question as answered if it is the case!